# LINQ to entities against EF in many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4 EF CodeFirst.

**Need help to write LINQ (to entities) code** in Index action to get collection of Courses which are attended by selected student. *The relationship is many to many with join table with payload.*

```
//StudentController
//-----------------------

public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    var viewModel = new StudentIndexViewModel();
    viewModel.Students = db.Students;

    if (id != null)
    {
        ViewBag.StudentId = id.Value;
        // *************PROBLEM IN LINE DOWN. HOW TO MAKE COURSES COLLECTION? 
        viewModel.Courses = db.Courses
            .Include(i => i.StudentsToCourses.Where(t => t.ObjStudent.FkStudentId == id.Value));
    }


    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The error I got is:

```
The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
```

I have modeles (the third one is for join table with payload):

```
//MODEL CLASSES
//-------------

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentToCourse> StudentsToCourses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentToCourse> StudentsToCourses { get; set; }
}

public class StudentToCourse
{
    public int StudentToCourseId { get; set; }
    public int FkStudentId { get; set; }
    public int FkCourseId { get; set; }
    public string Classroom { get; set; }

    public virtual Student ObjStudent { get; set; }
    public virtual Course ObjCourse { get; set; }
}
```

Then, here is modelview I need to pass to view

```
//VIEWMODEL CLASS
//---------------

public class StudentIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<StudentToCourse> StudentsToCourses { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF does not support conditional include's. You'll need to include all or nothing (ie no `Where`inside the `Include`)

If you need to get the data for just certain relations, you can select it into an anonymous type, something like (the obviously untested);

```
var intermediary = (from course in db.Courses
                    from stc in course.StudentsToCourses
                    where stc.ObjStudent.FkStudentId == id.Value
                    select new {item, stc}).AsEnumerable();
```

Obviously, this will require some code changes, since it's no longer a straight forward Course with a StudentsToCourses collection.

Comment: Thanks! I'm considering to use ViewBag to pass intermediary variable to view. Maybe the "AsNumerable()" should be replaced with "ToList()" ? What's your opinion?

Comment: @Branislav `AsEnumerable()` can be replaced by `ToList()`, yes. The only downside is if you're continuing the filtering on the result, in which creating a `List()` may be un-necessary overhead, and should be done after all filters have been applied.